# Recover Rcpp source file

Tags: r, rcpp

I successfully sourced a cpp file into the R environment using `sourceCpp('my_cpp_code.cpp')`, but I removed the 'my_cpp_code.cpp' by mistake. It is possible to recover the source code of my_cpp_code.cpp from the R environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temporary directory of your R session (`tempdir()`) will contain a folder named `sourceCpp-<architecture>->Rcpp-version>` with sub-directories named `sourcecpp_<random>`. One of these will contain your code (plus the autogenerated code).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe. `sourceCpp()` has a `cacheDir` argument (defaulting to `getOption("rcpp.cache.dir", tempdir())`) that specifies a location under which intermediate files, including the original source file, are saved. If the directory hasn't been cleaned up, you should find a folder there named `"sourceCpp-<platform-info>"` and under there, directories for each `sourceCpp` call you have done: these will contain the original file.